# Open an android application via shell command in python script

Tags: android, python, shell, monkeyrunner

So I have a python script to test an android app with the monkeyrunner tool and at a certain point in the script, I have command to launch the application on the mobile phone. The command is: `device.shell('monkey -p com.blah.blah -v 500')` and it works perfect. But my question is: "What is the meaning of the number 500?"

I found this command on a forum and some users are using the value 300 instead of 500 or other values.. For me it works with all of them but not without it. I just need to understand what the number does so I can fully understand what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey) this command will launch your application and send 500/300/200(as specified by you) pseudo-random events to it such as clicks, touches, or gestures.